# "This transaction is closed" after rollback

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm trying to do some schema changes inside a transaction manager provided by pyramid. I'm running into various issues trying to run commit after a rollback:

The simplified version is:

```
def get_version(conn):
    try:
        result = conn.execute('SELECT version FROM versions LIMIT 1')
        return result.scalar()
    except:
        conn.rollback()
        return 0

def m_version_table(conn):
    conn.execute('CREATE TABLE versions (version INT)')
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO versions VALUES (1)')

def handle(conn):
    ver = get_version(conn)
    m_version_table(conn)

# task started with pyramid's transaction manager
    with env['request'].tm as tm:
        handle(env['request'].dbsession)
```

The transactions are started implicitly, which I can see in the logs:

```
 BEGIN (implicit)
 SELECT version FROM versions LIMIT 1
 ()
 ROLLBACK

 BEGIN (implicit)
 CREATE TABLE versions (version INT)
 ()
 INSERT INTO versions VALUES (1)
 ()
 UPDATE versions SET version = %s
 (1,)
 ROLLBACK
```

If `versions` exists (and I run a different ALTER afterwards) everything works fine. But after the rollback, I just get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".venv/bin/schema_refresh", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('project', 'console_scripts', 'schema_refresh')()
  File ".../schema_refresh.py", line 270, in run
    handle(env['request'].dbsession, tm)
  File ".../transaction-2.4.0-py3.7.egg/transaction/_manager.py", line 140, in __exit__
    self.commit()
  File ".../transaction-2.4.0-py3.7.egg/transaction/_manager.py", line 131, in commit
    return self.get().commit()
...
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed
```

Why can't the next transaction be committed, even if a new transaction has been correctly started after the rollback? (`ROLLBACK` is followed by `BEGIN (implicit)`)

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. Is this about DB transaction handling, i.e. *why can't I commit a transaction that has been rolled back* or is this about why a commit is attempted on that rolled back transaction in your code? If the latter, please also mention the package involved here; I assume [transaction](https://pypi.org/project/transaction/); and also show the code using it. It would help to know how `conn` is created and used when that error raises.

Comment: @shmee Details added. The question is: why can't I commit the new transaction, which started after the rollback was issued?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**
It very much seems like it's not the new transaction that `__exit__` tries to commit in your example.
Calling `rollback` on the DB session does create a new session transaction, but that's not joined with the transaction that the manager tracks within the context. Your subsequent calls to `execute` are done in the new session transaction, but `commit` is called on the original, first transaction, created when entering the context.

---

Assuming that you used `cookiecutter` to set up your project, your `models.__init__.py` will probably be the [default from the repo](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid-cookiecutter-starter/blob/latest/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/sqlalchemy_models/__init__.py).

That means that `env['request'].tm` returns a Zope [`TransactionManager`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/transaction/blob/master/transaction/_manager.py#L63) and, when entering its context, the [`begin()`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/transaction/blob/master/transaction/_manager.py#L70-L79) method instantiates a [`Transaction`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/transaction/blob/master/transaction/_transaction.py#L68) object and [stores it in the `_txn` attribute](https://github.com/zopefoundation/transaction/blob/master/transaction/_manager.py#L77).

`env['request'].dbsession` returns an SQLAlchemy [`Session`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L610), after [registering](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid-cookiecutter-starter/blob/latest/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/sqlalchemy_models/__init__.py#L47) it with the transaction manager.
The `TransactionManager`'s `Transaction` is now [joined](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.sqlalchemy/blob/master/src/zope/sqlalchemy/datamanager.py#L83) with the `Session`'s [`SessionTransaction`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L102) and should control its end and outcome.

Rolling back the `SessionTransaction` while handling the exception raised in the `execute()` call bypasses the transaction manager. Calling its `commit()` or `rollback()` methods, as done later by `__exit__`, will have it still try to terminate the `SessionTransaction` you rolled back.
Also, there's no mechanism that would join the new transaction with the manager.

You can either use the transaction manager or opt for manual transaction control. Just stick with your choice and don't mix both.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `conn.execute` which is not tracked by the transaction manager (which, by default, only tracks changes done via the ORM). You can either 1) modify your code that does `zope.sqlalchemy.registry(session)` to set `initial_state='changed'` such that the default will be to COMMIT instead of ROLLBACK (the default avoids extra commits if it doesn't know something changed - for performance) or 2) mark specific sessions that do this with `zope.sqlalchemy.mark_changed(session)`.

Finally, `get_version` should be done by coordinating with the transaction manager so that the entire transaction doesn't go into a bad state (despite your rollback the manager is still marked aborted right now). To do this use `tm.savepoint()`:

```
def get_version(conn, tm):
    sp = tm.savepoint()
    try:
        result = conn.execute('SELECT version FROM versions LIMIT 1')
        return result.scalar()
    except:
        sp.rollback()
        return 0
```